# Смена информации в главном окне программы (python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Делаю простую программу, где в главном окне будет кнопка, при нажатии которой информация в этом окне меняется на другую (в моем случае появляются другие кнопки). Переход на новую страницу получился, но вот кнопка с первой страницы осталась, как сделать так, чтобы информация с предыдущей страницы исчезла и появлялись только кнопки со второй страницы? Также подскажите функцию для задания кнопки "назад" к предыдущей странице

```
import tkinter as tk
app=tk.Tk()
app.geometry("250x250")
text=tk.Text(app)
def page2():
    tk.Button(app, text="2").puck()
    tk.Button(app, text="3").puck()
    tk.Button(app, text="Назад").puck()
tk.Button(app, text="1").puck()
app.mainloop()
```

Новый код!

```
from tkinter import *
app=Tk()

def page2():
    qframe.pack()
    mainframe.pack_forget()
def page1():
    mainframe.pack()
    qframe.pack_forget()
mainframe=Frame(app).pack()
b1=Button(mainframe, text="1", command=page2).pack()

qframe=Frame(app)
b2=Button(qframe, text="2").pack()
b3=Button(qframe, text="Назад", command=page1).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Метод упаковки по-другому называется) По вопросу - каждую страницу сделайте отдельным Frame, при переходе на новую страницу старый фрейм скрывайте, новый отображайте. При переходе назад - наоборот, текущий скрывайте, предыдущий отображайте.

Comment: @insolor сделал как вы сказали, создал отдельные фреймы и связал их через кнопки с функциями, только проблема, информация с нового фрейма появляется, но со старого не прячется, команды nameframe.pack_forget() или destroy не работают(

Comment: Все работает, нужно код смотреть.

Comment: В вопрос тогда уже добавьте, комментарии для размещения блоков кода не подходят

Comment: @insolor дописал обновленный код в вопросе

Comment: `mainframe=Frame(app).pack()` - упаковку не объединяйте с присваиванием, перенесите на отдельную строку. Так вы везде None в переменные записываете. Если это поправить, все заработает - только что проверил.

Comment: @insolor спасибо Вам огромное! целый день мучился, не мог понять , в чем дело)